# what's the double arrow (<<: *django) mean in a docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, yaml

I see something like

```
   celerybeat:
     <<: *django
```

in https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django example docker files.

What does it mean? I can't google `<<: *`

Comment: That's a docker-compose.yml, not a Dockerfile. They have different file formats.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`<<` and `*` are both YAML keys (you can also think of them as operators). And one more key related to your question is `&`.

In YAML, you can define anchors and later use them. For example,

```
foo: &myanchor
  key1: "val1"
  key2: "val2"

bar: *myanchor
```

In this code snippet, `&` defines an anchor names it `myanchor`, and `*myanchor` references that anchor. Now both `foo` and `bar` have the same keys and values.

`<<` is called the YAML **merge key**. You can compare it to class inheritance in OOP (not so accurate, but can help you understand). See below example.

```
foo: &myanchor
  key1: "val1"
  key2: "val2"

bar:
  << : *myanchor
  key2: "val2-new"
  key3: "val3"
```

In this code snippet, we merge keys and values from `foo` to `bar` but override the `key2` to a new value. And we add a new key-value pair to `bar`.

Now `bar` has the following value:

```json
{
  "bar": {
     "key1": "val1",
     "key2": "val2-new",
     "key3": "val3"
   }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the example to include the `:` after `<<` needed to make it a key.      As a minor note, `*` and `&` aren't really keys, they are indicators.    The merge key isn't formally a part of YAML, but an can be a useful extension, it is documented at http://yaml.org/type/merge.html